# How to add metadata to a tibble

Tags: r, metadata, tidyr, tibble

How does one add metadata to a tibble?

I would like a sentence describing each of my variable names such that I could print out the tibble with the associated metadata and if I handed it to someone who hadn't seen the data before, they could make some sense of it.

```
as_tibble(iris)

# A tibble: 150 × 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>  <fctr>
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
# ... with 140 more rows

# Sepal.length. Measured from sepal attachment to stem
# Sepal.width. Measured at the widest point
# Petal.length. Measured from petal attachment to stem
# Petal.width. Measured at widest point
# Species. Nomenclature based on Integrated Taxonomic Information System (ITIS), January 2018.
```

thanks!

Comment: `?comment` will likely be what you are looking for

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed response.  But this topic has been bugging me since I first started learning R.  In my work, assigning metadata to columns is not just common. It is required.  That R didn't seem to have a nice way to do it was really bothering me.  So much so, that I wrote some packages to do it.

The [fmtr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fmtr/index.html) package has a function to assign the descriptions (plus other stuff).  And the [libr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/libr/index.html) package has a dictionary function, so you can look at all the metadata you assign.

Here is how it works:

First, assign the descriptions to the columns.  You just send a named list into to the `descriptions()` function.

```
library(fmtr)
library(libr)

# Create data frame
df <- iris

# Assign descriptions
descriptions(df) <- list(Sepal.Length = "Measured from sepal attachment to stem", 
                         Sepal.Width = "Measured at the widest point",
                         Petal.Length = "Measured from petal attachment to stem", 
                         Petal.Width = "Measured at the widest point",
                         Species = paste("Nomanclature based on Integrated Taxonomic", 
                                         "Information System (ITIS), January 2018."))
```

Then you can see all the metadata by calling the `dictionary()` function, like so:

```
dictionary(df)
# # A tibble: 5 x 10
#  Name  Column      Class  Label Description                                                 
#  <chr> <chr>       <chr>  <chr> <chr>                                                      
# 1 df    Sepal.Leng~ numer~ NA    Measured from sepal attachment to stem                     
# 2 df    Sepal.Width numer~ NA    Measured at the widest point                                
# 3 df    Petal.Leng~ numer~ NA    Measured from petal attachment to stem                      
# 4 df    Petal.Width numer~ NA    Measured at the widest point                                 
# 5 df    Species     factor NA    Nomanclature based on Integrated Taxonomic Information Syst~
```

If you like, you can return the dictionary as its own data frame, then save it or print it or whatever.

```
d <- dictionary(df)
```

Here is the dictionary data frame:

[image: dictionary data frame]

Answer (score 14):

This seems tricky. In principle @hrbrmstr's comment is the way to go (i.e. use `?comment` or `?attr` to add attributes to any object), but these attributes *will not be printed out by default*. Attributes seem to be printed automatically for *atomic* objects:

```
> z <- 1:6
> attr(z,"hello") <- "goodbye"
> z
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
attr(,"hello")
[1] "goodbye"
```

... but not, alas, for data frames or tibbles:

```
dd <- tibble::tibble(x=1:4,y=2:5)
> attr(dd,"metadata") <- c("some stuff","some more stuff")
> dd
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      x     y
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     2     3
3     3     4
4     4     5
```

You can wrap the object with its own S3 class to get this stuff printed:

```
class(dd) <- c("my_tbl",class(dd))
> print.my_tbl <- function(x) {
+    NextMethod(x)
+    print(attr(x,"metadata"))
+    invisible(x)
+ }
> dd
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      x     y
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     2     3
3     3     4
4     4     5
[1] "some stuff"      "some more stuff"
```

You could make the printing more elaborate or pretty, e.g.

```
cat("\nMETADATA:\n")
cat(sprintf("# %s",attr(x,"metadata")),sep="\n")
```

Nothing bad will happen if the other user hasn't defined `print.my_tbl` (the print method will fall back to the print method for tibbles), but the metadata will only be printed if they have your `print.my_tbl` definition ...

Comment: This is very helpful Ben.  Is there any way to do something similar but would only print the attributes at the time a table is loaded from an RDS file?

Comment: that seems very tricky indeed.  It's hard for the print method for an object to know whether the object has just been loaded or has been in the session for a while. The simplest way I can think of to manage this is to (1) add "print_attributes" as an argument to `print.my_tbl` (with default FALSE); (2) write a dedicated `read_my_tbl()` function that calls `x <- readRDS(...)` and `print(x, print_attributes=TRUE)`, then returns `invisible(x)` (so the object doesn't get printed again.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I had the same thought and am using a custom read function currently.  Glad to know there isn't a simpler solution at least!

Answer (score 6):

This is not all that different than Ben Bolker's suggestions, but conceptually, if I want information to be related to the vectors in my data frame, I would prefer they be directly tied to the vectors.  In other words, I'd prefer to add the attributes to the vectors themselves rather than to the data frame object.

I don't know that I would go so far as to add a custom class to the object, but perhaps a separate function you can call up for a data frame-like object would be adequate:

```
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(labelVector)

print_with_label <- function(dframe){
  stopifnot(inherits(dframe, "data.frame"))
  labs <- labelVector::get_label(dframe, names(dframe))
  labs <- sprintf("%s: %s", names(dframe), labs)
  print(dframe)
  cat("\n")
  cat(labs, sep = "\n")
}

iris <- 
  as_tibble(iris) %>%  
  set_label(Sepal.Length = "This is a user friendly label",
            Petal.Length = "I much prefer reading human over computer")

print_with_label(iris)

mtcars <-
  set_label(mtcars,
            mpg = "Miles per Gallon",
            qsec = "Quarter mile time",
            hp = "Horsepower",
            cyl = "Cylinders",
            disp = "Engine displacement")

print_with_label(mtcars)
```